# Does indeterminacy imply contingency?

Tags: determinism, principle-of-sufficient-reason

If there is true indeterminacy in the world, does this imply that each state of affairs is contingent? I am assuming that by contingent, we mean that things could have happened otherwise.

Conceptually, it is not hard to imagine a series of events that are metaphysically necessary and yet may occur without any cause and thus without determination.

Does this imagination imply that you can have an indeterministic series of events that are still necessary? If so, does this still violate the principle of sufficient reason?

Graham Oppy states that a necessary thing can have an explanation for its existence:  the explanation being that it is necessary. As such, can the explanation for why an indeterministic series of events exists be that it is necessary?

Comment: It does not imply that every event is contingent. There could be fated events that shall happen regardless of which contingent path is taken in between them (as Greeks believed), or events imposed by God, such as the first and the second coming of the Savior  (as Christians believe). As long as not every event is necessary, full-blown PSR is false, an "explanation" of contingent events is not a sufficient reason for their actualized specifics. Indeterminism is out of place here because determinism is not the only way of necessitation.

Comment: @Conifold Thanks for your comment, once again. You stated that it does not imply that every event is contingent. But can every event still be necessary with determinism still being false? And is this equivalent to the kind of fatalism you described but for every event and not just a subset?

Comment: `Conceptually, it is not hard to imagine a series of events that are metaphysically necessary and yet may occur without any cause and thus without determination.` - like what?

Answer (score 0):

If we start from modal indeterminacy itself, we will have second-order possibilities available, in which at least second-order contingency can then be found. To wit, suppose a modal variable *X*ψ, where ψ is some fact(oid) and  *X* is either ◊, ~◊, ◊~, or ~◊~. If *X* is underdetermined by other fact(oid)s, then we seem to mean to say that it is possible for *X* to be assigned any of the four ◊-values given in general. So we seem to have:

1. ◊◊ψ
2. ◊~◊ψ
3. ◊◊~ψ
4. ◊~◊~ψ

(3) means that ψ is possibly contingent. Now, in the usual modal logic, the iteration of the operators is more or less superfluous, e.g. "possibly possible" = "there is some possible world according to which in some possible world it is the case that..." which seems to collapse to just "there is some possible world where it is the case that..." and so on. On the other hand, if the second-order possibility *is* nontrivial, then let us compose (1) through (4) so as to write something like:

5. ◊(◊ψ ∨ ~◊ψ ∨ ◊~ψ ∨ ~◊~ψ)

... and interpret this as meaning it is second-order contingent (because possible) that *X* comes out to one of the specific values. Is second-order contingency good enough for present purposes, then?

Answer (score 0):

In a probabilistic world nothing is completely determined by prior causes. Each cause determines only the probability distribution of the effect.

For each cause there is an infinite number of possible effects and the highest probability is near the average value of the probability distribution.

Nothing occurs without a cause, but causes never determine their effects with absolute accuracy.

Comment: If you include the random value generation in the list of "causes", then you still have future states completely caused by past causes, where the past causes "determine" their effects with absolute accuracy.

Comment: I mean, let's say you have some quantum dice, and you've arranged some situation where if that dice rolls a 4, X happens, and if it rolls any other number, Y happens -- if you include all prior causes up until that dice roll, then you still can't determine if X or Y happens perfectly, BUT if you also include the result of the dice roll itself in the "list of prior causes", that kind of changes the language you use about it. Even though the dice roll wasn't determined, it itself was a cause for the next state, and a cause which, when considered, guaranteed the following state.

Comment: @TKoL Randomness is not in the cause. Randomness is the inaccuracy of the effect. Dice roll was caused by the player's throwing move. The result is random, because the player could not *decide* the result.

Comment: Says who? Why is randomness not in the cause? Randomness is, in fact, the very cause of the inaccuracy of the effect - the effect can't be accurately predicted before hand "beCAUSE" of the randomness.

Comment: @TKoL Now you are just playing with words. Randomness is not a cause and inaccuracy is not an effect.  Randomness *is* the inaccuracy. Causes are known things, we predict the effects based on our knowledge of the causes.

Comment: I don't think I'm playing around unreasonably. I'm a software dev. I know that a random number generator *is* part of the causal flow of any program that isn't deterministic. The random number it generates *is causal towards future things*. Imagine a digital dice, you roll 2: The reason it chose 2 this time, and not 6 or 5 or 4 or 3 or 1 -- that reason is at least at a surface level "uncaused", but that doesn't mean it itself is not a cause for later things. You use randomness in programs to cause things in the future. That's what randomness is. It's an uncaused cause.

Comment: I think this discussion is pointless and you guys are talking over each other. Perhaps the vocabulary of sufficient and insufficient causes may help. In quantum mechanics, the initial state may be a necessary condition for A or B to happen. But the initial state may not directly imply A or B. There would be no reason as to why A rather than B occurs.

Comment: This is only true if there’s no deterministic theory that underpins or replaces quantum mechanics though. If there isn’t, everything  becomes metaphysically necessary.

Comment: @TKoL Randomness has nothing to do with causality.  You should not conflate them. Randomness is just one kind of indeterminacy (the other kind is free will). All events are caused and all events are partially random, i.e. not completely determined by the cause.

Comment: " Randomness has nothing to do with causality" so random events have nothing to do with how the future unfolds?

Comment: @TKoL Of course randomness affects the future. The effects are always a little different than what the cause would suggest. Randomness is neither a cause nor an effect, randomness is just a modifier between them.

Comment: Okay, guess we just have different semantic understandings of what it means for something to be a "cause". If a source of randomness has the ability to affect the future -- I mean, to me that's the beginning and end of what it means to be a 'cause'. Perhaps you disagree there, and that's okay.